# Can I jump to an actual virtual address in Lua?

Tags: lua

Let's say I know the address of a function from a DLL file:

```
0x7A0BA032: hello_world() { printf("Hello World!"); }
```

Is it somehow possible to call this function from within Lua bytecode?

pre-compiled Lua file: **hello_world.lua**

```
JMP 0x7A0BA032
```

and then call it e.g. like

```
dofile "hello_world.lua"
```

Is there a chance that something like this works?

Assume that I cannot use `loadlib()` or anything to simply load a DLL and call its methods ..

Comment: No change in pure Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a chance that something like this works?

That could *never* work. Not in Lua, not in LuaJIT, not even in ***C***. Many modern OS's randomize the memory addresses that code is loaded into, precisely to *prevent* external code from statically knowing the address of a particular function.

At the very least, you would need a way to query the address of that function at runtime. And regular Lua doesn't provide that. A Lua module could provide the ability to load DLLs and marshal calls to/from Lua. LuaJIT has an FFI that does something similar.

But all of those rely on runtime queries of the function's address. As such, they could never be baked into a compiled Lua script.

Comment: That's a pity. I try to mod a game ([Supreme Commander](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/Lua)) which appears to have it's own modified version of Lua 5.0 where it removed all that useful stuff like `loadlib`. I can't even create something like a pipe to have at least inter-process communication going or anything.

Comment: @displayname: One of the primary purposes of Lua is that it allows you to create a neigh-impregniable sandbox scripting environment. If the owning system doesn't want you to have IPC, then you can't. If the owning system doesn't want you to talk to DLLs, then you can't. No matter what. This is a *feature* of the language.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the additional information. Seems like I have to go another direction here.. My plan was to add support for "remote" controlled AIs but it looks like it's way harder to do that than I thought ..